# Not able to pass data from one component to other in angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-template

This is very basic setup where I am trying to create a simple reusable data-table component. But its not working.

**data_table.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {TAB_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
@Component({
    selector: 'data_table',
    templateUrl: './data_table/data_table.html',
    directives: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, TAB_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class DataTableComponent {
    @Input()
    rows: Array<any>;
}
```

**data_table.html:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>sr</td>
            <td>name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row in rows">
            <td>{{row.sr}}</td>
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**employee.component.ts:**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {DataTableComponent} from '../../data_table/data_table.component';

const Emps: Array < any > = [{
    sr: 1,
    name: 'saurabh'
}, {
    sr: 2,
    name: 'arun'
}];

@Component({
    selector: 'employee',
    templateUrl: './app/employee/employee.html',
    directives: [DataTableComponent, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

export class EmployeeComponent {
    emps = Emps;
}
```

**employee.html:**

```
<div>
   <data-table [rows]="emps"></data-table> 
</div>
```

I don't have any error in the console but the rows are not getting populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quess you have few typos in your code.

Your `DataTableComponent` have a wrong `selector` and within your template you need to use `of` operator in your for loop statement instead of `in`.

So try to change following lines:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'data-table', <== '_' => '-'

<tr *ngFor="let row of rows"> <==  'in' => `of'
```